# Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) "tl-wn821n"

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, monitoring

I'm trying to put my adapter in monitor mode, but occurs the error: Error for wireless request set mode.

```
iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A10 Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1962
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0107  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] [8086:1237] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II] [8086:7000]
00:01.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE [8086:7111] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: ata_piix, ata_generic
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter [80ee:beef]
    Kernel driver in use: vboxvideo
    Kernel modules: vboxvideo
00:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
    Kernel modules: e1000
00:04.0 System peripheral [0880]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service [80ee:cafe]
    Kernel driver in use: vboxguest
    Kernel modules: vboxguest
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller [8086:2415] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller [1028:0177]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0
    Kernel modules: snd_intel8x0
00:06.0 USB controller [0c03]: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB [106b:003f]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
    Kernel modules: ohci_pci
00:07.0 Bridge [0680]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI [8086:7113] (rev 08)
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4
00:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
    Kernel modules: e1000
00:0d.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2829] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted.
```

Comment: Does `iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor` work?

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337712/iwconfig-during-boot-operation-not-permitted

Comment: Unfortunately no, it does not work.

Comment: I'm using the root user, I think it is not going to work.

Comment: You have to set your device down, change the mode and back up. Also, stopping NetworkManager ensures your device is not repurposed in the meantime

Comment: @AndréMilke Did you find any solution for this? If yes, Please do update it.

Comment: This adapter is not compatible to monitor mode. I bought another and it works well.